# STRef and phantom types

Tags: haskell

Does `s` in `STRef s a` get instantiated with a concrete type? One could easily imagine some code where `STRef` is used in a context where the  `a` takes on `Int`. But there doesn't seem to be anything for the type inference to give `s` a concrete type.

Imagine something in pseudo Java like `MyList<S, A>`. Even if `S` never appeared in the implementation of `MyList` instantiating a concrete type like `MyList<S, Integer>` where a concrete type is not used in place of `S` would not make sense. So how can `STRef s a` work?

Comment: @CarstenKönig I'm not sure if it gets compiled out at some stage, but in GHC Core polymorphic type variables are explicitly applied as function arguments, similarly to how a pi type works in a dependently typed language.

Comment: @DavidYoung Thanks! As I said: I have no clue about the way it get handeled in the background - are there some resources where I can educate myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr - in practice it seems it always gets initialised to `RealWorld` in the end**

The [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-ST.html#ST) notes that `s` can be instantiated to `RealWorld` inside invocations of `stToIO`, but is otherwise uninstantiated:

> -- The s parameter is either
>
> --   an uninstantiated type variable (inside invocations of 'runST'), or
>
> --   'RealWorld' (inside invocations of 'Control.Monad.ST.stToIO').

Looking at the actual code for `ST` however it seems `runST` uses a specific value `realWorld#`:

```
newtype ST s a = ST (STRep s a)
type STRep s a = State# s -> (# State# s, a #)

runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
runST st = runSTRep (case st of { ST st_rep -> st_rep })

runSTRep :: (forall s. STRep s a) -> a
runSTRep st_rep = case st_rep realWorld# of
                        (# _, r #) -> r
```

`realWorld#` is defined as a [magic primitive inside the GHC source code](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/basicTypes/MkId.lhs#L1023):

```
realWorldName     = mkWiredInIdName gHC_PRIM  (fsLit "realWorld#")
                                    realWorldPrimIdKey realWorldPrimId

realWorldPrimId :: Id   -- :: State# RealWorld
realWorldPrimId = pcMiscPrelId realWorldName realWorldStatePrimTy
                     (noCafIdInfo `setUnfoldingInfo` evaldUnfolding
                                  `setOneShotInfo` stateHackOneShot)
```

You can also confirm this in `ghci`:

```
Prelude> :set -XMagicHash
Prelude> :m +GHC.Prim
Prelude GHC.Prim> :t realWorld#
realWorld# :: State# RealWorld
```

Comment: I saw this too - I must admit, that I have no clue what the `#` are all about - can you help me here?

Comment: I believe in general just indicate unboxed things (e.g. tuples), though `State#` is part of GHC's internal implementation of forcing proper ordering for the `IO` monad so may be a little bit more magic.

Answer (score 4):

From your question I can not see if you understand why the phantom `s` type is there at all. Even if you did not ask for this explicitly, let me elaborate on that.

### The role of the phantom type

The main use of the phantom type is to constrain references (aka pointers) to stay "inside" the ST monad. Roughly, the dynamically allocated data must end its life when `runST` returns.

To see the issue, let's pretend that the type of `runST` were

```
runST :: ST s a -> a
```

Then, consider this:

```
data Dummy
let var :: STRef Dummy Int
    var    = runST (newSTRef 0)
    change :: () -> ()
    change = runST (modifySTRef var succ)
    access :: () -> Int
    result :: (Int, ())
    result = (access() , change())
 in result
```

(Above I added a few useless `()` arguments to make it similar to imperative code)

Now what should be the result of the code above? It could be either `(0,())` or `(1,())` depending on the evaluation order. This is a big no-no in the pure Haskell world.

The issue here is that `var` is a reference which "escaped" from its `runST`. When you escape the ST monad, you are no longer forced to use the monad operator `>>=` (or equivalently, the `do` notation to sequentialize the order of side effects. If references are still around, then we can still have side effects around when there should be none.

To avoid the issue, we restrict `runST` to work on `ST s a` **where `a` does not depend on `s`**. Why this? Because `newSTRef` returns a `STRef s a`, a reference to `a` tagged with the phantom type `s`, hence the return type depends on `s` and can not be extracted from the ST monad through `runST`.

Technically, this restriction is done by using a rank-2 type:

```
runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

the "forall" here is used to implement the restriction. The type is saying: choose any `a` you wish, then provide a value of type `ST s a` for any `s` I wish, then I will return an `a`. Mind that `s` is chosen by `runST`, not by the caller, so it could be absolutely anything. So, the type system will accept an application `runST action` only if `action :: forall s. ST s a` where `s` is unconstrained, and `a` does not involve `s` (recall that the caller has to choose `a` before `runST` chooses `s`).

It is indeed a slightly hackish trick to implement the independence constraint, but it does work.

### On the actual question

To connect this to your actual question: in the implementation of `runST`, `s` will be chosen to be any concrete type. Note that, even if `s` were simply chosen to be `Int` inside `runST` it would not matter much, because the type system has already constrained `a` to be independent from `s`, hence to be reference-free. As @Ganesh pointed out, `RealWorld` is the type used by GHC.

You also mentioned Java. One could attempt to play a similar trick in Java as follows: (warning, overly simplified code follows)

```
interface ST<S,A> { A call(); }
interface STAction<A> { <S> ST<S,A> call(S dummy); }
...
<A> A runST(STAction<A> action} {
    RealWorld dummy = new RealWorld();
    return action.call(dummy).call();
}
```

Above in `STAction` parameter `A` can not depend on `S`.

Comment: How it is that at the end runST retreives the value? What role is playing readSTRef? Is it 'freeing' a from s. My understanding is the following neeSTRef lock s to a destroying any polymorphism of s, giving such ref to runST will make the compiler yell "don't give me  type with zero degree if freedom I need to choise my implementation" then enters readSTRef which gives back to the ST ref it's 'freedom' in s? One more thing does it mean than after readSTRef and runST the value is destroyed (fully consume) nothing can be done with it?